# USB-A 12V Output?

Tags: voltage, usb, dc-dc-converter

I am very confused by PowerBanks. We bought some power banks and I can read this on the back:

[image]

It seems the power bank can output 12V through the USB cable. Is that true?

Comment: What is true? That you can get 12V output ? How?

Comment: @Winny USB-A does not use PD, but Quick Charge.

Comment: Is there any devices that can do the initial dialog to enable the 12V output ?

Comment: @nowox That would be a new question

Comment: Many devices like mobile phones do that to get higher voltages. Maybe that's not what you meant to ask?

Comment: @winny 12 V also isn't one of the standard voltages USB PD supports; Quickcharge uses 12 V but PD goes straight from 9 to 15 (unless you use the more precise voltage negotiation mode that I've never known anything to support).

Comment: you want a "Power Trigger Module" for usb, either fixed to 12v or customizable with a button or mcu. they are on ebay for a few bucks.